# A cell phone company offers 6 different voice packages and 8 different data packages...

Tags: combinatorics

Can anyone help me with this question?

> A cell phone company offers 6 different voice packages and 8 different data packages. Of those, 3 packages include both voice and data. How many ways are there to choose either voice or data, but not both?

Well I think the simple part is using the rule of addition to get that there are 14 ways to choose either voice or data. Now I have to determine what I have to subtract from this number.

Maybe the answer is simply (6-3) + (8-3) = 8.

Can anyone give me an idea how I should be thinking to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: It always helps to reduce the problem to a simple case you can understand, then gradually augment the complexity until you get to the original problem. So how about this version: I have 3 shirts and 2 pairs of pants, and one of these combinations is all red. How many outfits are *not* all red ? Can you extrapolate here to your case?

Comment: Thanks @DerekAllums that's helpful. If I wanted to make my case exactly like yours, it would be a case where I could either wear shorts or a shirt, but not both, which can lead to some embarrasment obviously. So your example is a little different and I would likely be going (3-1)x(2-1) = 2. I'm multiplying with your example, but adding with my example.

Comment: Yes good point, indeed it's not exactly the same, but the general principle is still valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

You are looking for the number of elements in the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of the two sets.  The symmetric difference of two sets $A$ and $B$ is
$$A \triangle B = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) = (A \cap B') \cup (A' \cap B)$$
or
$$A \triangle B = (A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)$$
Since the sets $A \cap B'$ and $A' \cap B$ are disjoint,
$$|A \triangle B| = |A \cap B'| + |A' \cap B|$$
Since $A \cap B \subseteq A \cup B$,
$$|A \triangle B| = |A \cup B| - |A \cap B|$$
By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle),
$$|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$$
so
$$|A \triangle B| = |A \cup B| - |A \cap B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap B| = |A| + |B| - 2|A \cap B|$$

Let $D$ and $V$ be, respectively, the sets of data and voice packages.  You obtained
$$|D \triangle V| = |D \cap V'| + |D' \cap V| = (8 - 3) + (6 - 3) = 5 + 3 = 8$$

Alternatively,
$$|D \triangle V| = |D| + |V| - 2|D \cap V| = 8 + 6 - 2 \cdot 3 = 8$$

Comment: Great answer. How would I say $(A \cap B')$ in words? Does $B'$ mean "not in B"? Just trying to understand some of your notation.

Comment: $A \cap B'$ is the intersection of set $A$ with the complement of set $B$.  The complement of set $B$ is the set of all elements in the universe that are not in set $B$.

Comment: Thank you. @T.G.Taussig